# How to enable MFA in the Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to test MFA on a new user. For that I followed below steps:

- I have logged in the Snowflake as Account admin.
- Created a user as below

  - `create user <USER> password='XYZ'`
  - `alter user <USER> SET DISABLE_MFA = FALSE`

When tried to login I was not prompted for Authentication code. Did I miss any steps?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake users can self-enroll in MFA through the web interface

Follow the steps in this [post](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/ui-preferences.html#enrolling-in-mfa-multi-factor-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

To add to @mdem7 point, Presently Snowflake *only* allows users to enroll into MFA, so you cannot force it on from the start. But you can use the `MINS_TO_BYPASS_MFA = <integer>` [option](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-user.html) to give the use `N` minutes to login and setup MFA before they have to MFA turned on.

Which means you can create an account send the details to a user and tell them "setup MFA within N minutes or you will be locked out" and know they ether setup it, or where locked out.

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake MFA setup process requires that the user have DUO configured on their phone and that number has to be associated with the Snowflake login account. This can only be done by the user after logging into the account.

DISABLE_MFA = FALSE

"This property has no effect if the user is not currently enrolled in MFA (i.e. EXT_AUTHN_DUO = FALSE). As such, it is typically only set when using ALTER USER to disable MFA for a user."

The https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-user.html